# Allow only certain string at XML tag with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I search for a way to check with my xsd that, a certain tag only one of different allowed strings contains.

E.g. two allowed strings are:

- Index
- Condition

**OK:**

```
<TYPE>Index</TYPE>
<TYPE>Condition</TYPE>
```

**WRONG:**

```
<TYPE>Integer</TYPE>
```

The definition from type in my xsd is as follows:

```
  <xs:element name="TYPE">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`xs:enumeration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-enumeration):

```
<xs:element name="TYPE">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Index"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Condition"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```